# opencart 3 - delivery date - for after 4 days on product page

Tags: opencart

i use opencart v3.
**I would like to print the product delivery date on the product page after 4 days. but I would like to have an additional 1 day to be added in the 4 day period if there is Sunday. I want to take the day value (4) in the sku field.**

If today was Monday, the date of after 4 days would be shown. But today is Friday and Friday's order will be added to calculation for 1 more day. Because there is Sunday between the days. I would also like to retract  the number 4 from the area SKU. Could you specify please.

like this (edit)

```
{"dateString": "30-01-2019"}

{% set curDate = "now"|date %}
{% set start = 4 %}
{% set dates = [] %}
{% if dateString != "" %}
{% set dates = dateString|split(",") %}
{% endif %}

{% for i in 0..4 %}
{% set curDate = curDate|date_modify("+1 day") %}
{% if curDate|date("N") != "7" and i >= start and (curDate|date("d-m-Y")) in dates == false %}
{{curDate|date("d-m-Y")}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

result and full code: https://twigfiddle.com/9rgwd5

there is ok. 4 days after Sunday excluding date.

how do I change the value of sku with the value "4" here?

Comment: Can you look at rewriting your question? It's not very clear what you have done, or what you're trying to achieve. Happy to help once it's clearer

Comment: want to show the product delivery date in the product page. today + 4 days I want to calculate. but on Sunday it is necessary to add an additional 1 day. example: the date on the product page today: 06 Feb 2019. (today + 4 days and +1 day for Sunday). The product page should look like this: estimated date of February 06, 2019. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will add a number of days to the current date based on whether today is Sunday or not.

```
Today is {{ "now"|date('l') }} {# shows the current day of week #}

{% if "now"|date("l") == "Sunday" %} {# if today is Sunday #}
    {{ "now"|date_modify("+1 day")|date("m/d/Y") }} {# add one day and display #}
{% else %}
    {{ "now"|date_modify("+4 day")|date("m/d/Y") }} {# add four days and display #}
{% endif %}
```

It may be a good idea to use [TwiggFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/) in order to test your script easily

Comment: Idea is good but seems this code not meet request requirements... one additional day (sunday) should be added if not enough four days for shipping on the week.. in another words  if customer open product on monday or tuesday not need to add additional day.. if product will be opened on for example on friday,  you should add one additional day for delivery...

Comment: @K.B. why don't we let the user, who has not been very clear, confirm if this worked or not. You can always post your own answer if you feel this is not correct. I thought I'd take 5 mins to show him the right direction since this will question would probably be closed

Comment: thank you for your interest Daniel, this code work. but only on Sunday, it adds 1 day. example: today I would like to add an additional 1 day because it is on Sunday when adding 4 days on friday. (Because in 4 days there is on Sunday)

Comment: @Metin It's probably the language barrier but I cannot what you want. I have comments in line explaining what each line does, you should be able to figure it out from there. Just change the `"+1 day"` for the Sunday condition or the `"+4 day"` for the other days

Comment: If today was Monday, the date of after 4 days would be shown. But today is Friday and Friday's order will be added to calculation for 1 more day. Because there is Sunday between the days. I would also like to retract  the number 4 from the area SKU. Could you specify please, thank you.

Comment: @Daniel thank you for twigfiddle.com. good there is exaples

Comment: @Metin so any order takes 4 days for delivery but Sunday orders take 5 days?

Comment: Yes @Daniel thats right. its ok. but now i cant show month turkish. ex: now echo 02 but i want to 02 instead of subat (february turkish), do you know?

Comment: @Metin you want to show the word "February" (in turkish) instead of "02"? If you look at the code `date("m/d/Y")` each letter represents a value, there are many ways you can change the layout, try this page for examples: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.date.php

Comment: @Daniel yes i looked there. recommended this usage: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8'); but which file change this setting in opencart 3, do you know that?

Comment: @Metin unfortunately not. Perhaps you should try the OpenCart forums?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Daniel

Comment: Great, if my answer helped, please accept it, or any other answer that worked for you @Metin

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand main request I little bit improve Daniel code...

```
 Today is {{ "now"|date('l') }} {# shows the current day of week #}

{% if ("now"|date("l") == "Monday" or "now"|date("l") == "Tuesday" or "now"|date("l") == "Wednesday") %} {# if today is monday tuesday or wednesday #}
    {{ "now"|date_modify("+4 day")|date("m/d/Y") }} {# add 4 day and display #}
{% else %}
    {{ "now"|date_modify("+5 day")|date("m/d/Y") }} {# add 5 (4 plus sunday) days and display #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you @K. B. If today was Monday, the date of after 4 days would be shown. But today is Friday and Friday's order will be added to calculation for 1 more day. Because there is Sunday between the days. I would also like to retract  the number 4 from the area SKU. Could you specify please, thank you

Comment: @Metin what you mean? "I would also like to retract the number 4 from the area SKU" can you explain more details?

Comment: cargo day value (here "4"), I want to get (include) product page sku input value (in admin panel product page)